# Perl regex no working if using square brackets as delimiter. Why?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm very experienced with Perl and regex. However, this is making me crazy, I just can't find an answer to it and I cannot see a reason for it either. Please look at the following code:

```
my $str = 'Hello[world]';

say $str =~ m/\w+\[.*?\]/ ? 'Yes' : 'No';
say $str =~ m[\w+\[.*?\]] ? 'Yes' : 'No';
say $str =~ m(\w+\[.*?\]) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

The output of this is:

```
Yes
No
Yes
```

As you can see, the only thing I'm changing is the regex delimiter, and the expression is not working as I would expect when the delimiter is square brackets.

Can someone please explain why the second one is not matching?

Thanks in advance,

Francisco

Comment: Please do not confuse yourself by using `[]` or `()` as delimiters. (Because they have special meaning in regex).

Comment: I guess you'd need to double-escape the square brackets (though I'm not sure whether that is possible at all). How would the interpreter distinguish between literal brackets, character classes, and delimiters?

Comment: @Bergi: [Gory details of parsing quoted constructs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs)

Comment: @nhahtdh: That's not an answer. I don't confuse myself. That's why Perl allows you to chose delimiters and they should work as long as you code correctly and you don't find a bug. I'm resisting myself to believe I found a bug in something so basic, that's why I want to find the exact explanation to this question.

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo: That is a comment, I never tried to answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [B::Deparse](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?B%3a%3aDeparse) module comes to your rescue:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse foo.pl
my $str = 'Hello[world]';
say $str =~ /\w+\[.*?\]/u ? 'Yes' : 'No';
say $str =~ /\w+[.*?]/u ? 'Yes' : 'No';
say $str =~ /\w+\[.*?\]/u ? 'Yes' : 'No';
foo.pl syntax OK
```

As you can see, the escaping of `[ ]` in your regex meant that perl now interpreted them as meta characters, and not delimiters. You need two levels of escape. Which I am not sure is even possible to do, since `\\` will be interpreted as literal backslash.

To be extra clear: In a normal regex, the brackets `[]` have a meta character status. So in order to match them literally, they need to be escaped. When using them as delimiters, you *add* another meta character status to them: They are also delimiters. So both meta character statuses need to be escaped.

This will work as intended:

```
say $str =~ m[\w+\Q\[\E.*?\Q\]\E] ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

Of course, the lesson here is to choose your delimiters wisely.

Comment: Yes, I see it. But why? They are escaped exactly the same way 3 times. Now, how would you escape them?

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo Like I said in my answer: You need two levels of escape. The `[]` brackets have two different meta statuses when you use them as delimiters as well.

Comment: Ok, so, when you scape them once, what exactly are you scaping? Because according to Deparse, it ends up exactly as if you don't escape anything at all.

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo You escape their status as delimiters. Just like if you had done `/\/\//` (`m#//#`).

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo: Check the link I posted under your question. It should give some insight on how the parser processes the code.

Comment: @TLP: But I don't need to escape their delimiter status. If I don't escape them, they don't act as delimiters. The parser is supposed to not think of them as delimiters until it's balanced (first logical close-bracket). Now, if I chose the same example with other delimiters, this doesn't happen. For example, if the string was 'Hello(world)' and I try to match with m(\w+\(.*?\)), then it works as expected. Why is it that I don't have to double-escape parenthesis if they also have two different meta statuses?

Comment: @nhahtdh: Yes, I've been reading that too, thanks. Still doesn't quite explain the specific behavior of square brackets against other balanced delimiters like parenthesis or curly brackets.

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo You did not try `m(\w+(.*?))` in your code. You tried `m(\w+\[.*?\])`. However, if you do try that, and deparse it, you get `/\w+(.*?)/`, meaning that the parens are handled exactly like the brackets. They are however transparent in the regex and do not cause it to fail. Your wildcard string then includes the parens, and a non-anchored string of optional wildcards can never fail a regex.

Comment: @TLP: Thank you, you've helped me understand something new. It's amazing how one can have more than 10 years using a programming language and still find aspects that make you feel like a newbie. :-)

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo I know exactly what you mean. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `[` with `<` and `]` with `>` (or another similar substitutions) before performing the match.

Comment: Well... it was not an actual problem I didn't know how to resolve. I just really wanted to understand the reasons behind that behavior in the interpreter. But thanks anyway. :-)